# Div shifted to the right only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, drupal, styling

The breadcrumbs part of the page is shifted to the right (in Firefox) with no apparent reason.

HTML:

```
<div class="region region-header">
<section id="block-easy-breadcrumb-easy-breadcrumb" class="block block-easy-breadcrumb">
<section class="content">
<div id="breadcrumbs-one">
</section>
</section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #breadcrumbs-one
    {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF #FFFFFF #E7E7E7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Here is the link to site:
http://www.vegus.lv/kursi

It's not in english.
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the issue is in `#main`. when you change your margin to `-7px auto 40px;` The things work.

Also, if you do not want to make changes to `#main`, you need to change the padding of `#header, #footer` CSS with `10px 10px 8px;` values respectively.

There are 1px issues that have a conflicting inheritance or structural differences that tend to change the layout styles of some elements if not calculated properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was the first time I used stackoverflow. I must say you guys are awsome. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

try this please add `clear:left` on this below class

```
.region-header {
    clear: left;
    left: -19px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    width: 953px;
}
```

OR

add `float:left` on this below class

```
.region-header {
    float: left;
    left: -19px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    width: 953px;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is patchy. You are not solving the issue by finding out the right reason for the problem, but you are adding patches to make it work. Bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just add in CSS `float :left`.

```
#breadcrumbs-one {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF #FFFFFF #E7E7E7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you everybody. I hope I can help someone in return someday.